# Iphone UItabbarcontroller hide issue

Tags: ios4

i have created one iphone application. i have used my mainwindow.nib tab barcontroller and set the five navigation controller inside the tabbar. when my application start then open first page name(home page). i want to hide the tabbarController only this page.

thanks in advance

some coding  i have done. on delegate file.

```
// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line:

```
[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

This will hide the Bottom bar, i.e Tab bar.